# Django Rest Framework, Serializer Level Filter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models named Account and Story. With the help of a `models.Manager` on Django, I wrote a method that retrieves the stories posted in the last 24 hours. With Django, this method works very well. The problem is that when I create a serializer with Django Rest Framework it pulls all the stories. To prevent this, I wrote a method called `get_image_file` and used the method I wrote with the help of `models.Manager` here, but I could not solve the problem. As a result, how do I pull only the stories that were posted in the last 24 with Django Rest Framework, as I did on the Django side?

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from ..models import Account, Story


class StorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Story
        fields = ['image_file']

    def get_image_file(self, obj): 
    #This method doesn't work. DRF pulls all the stories.
        return obj.get_available_stories()

class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = '__all__'

    
    stories = StorySerializer(many=True)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
import datetime

def upload_to(instance, filename):
    username = instance.account.username
    return '%s/%s/%s' %('stories',username,filename)

def upload_pp(instance, filename):
    return '%s/%s/%s' %('profile_photo', instance.username,filename)

class Account(models.Model):
    username_pk = models.CharField(max_length=122)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=55, unique=True)
    profile_photo_id = models.CharField(max_length=155, unique=True)
    profile_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_pp, null=True, blank=True)
    profile_photo_width = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    profile_photo_height = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


class StoryManager(models.Manager):
    def get_available_stories(self, *args, **kwargs):
        date_from = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        return super(StoryManager, self).filter(image_timestamp__gte = date_from)

class Story(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(to=Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="stories")
    image_file = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to, blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
    image_url = models.URLField()
    image_pk = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True, editable=False, unique=True)
    image_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    image_width = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    image_height = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    objects = StoryManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.account)
```

Answer (score 0):

An way to do that is using Filters Class.
Works very similar as Serializer class.

[Custom Generic Filter](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#custom-generic-filtering)

```py
def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
    # Override this method to do your filtering.
    # Probably your BaseModel has some filed as created_at
    # Assuming that is a Datetime object
    return queryset.filter(created_at.hour__lte=24)
    # You can even sort this values adding a .sort_by() after the filter
```

Comment: Thank you but I couldn't solve the problem in this way. I solved it another way.

Comment: Nice to hear that !! @AdilHaydar.
This way that I showed is for me the best practice to do it...
Its Works just like serializers and you could re-use the Filter Class for others purposes.